# how to add days to java simple date format

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

How should I add 120 days to my current date which I got using simple date format?

I have seen few posts about it but couldn't get it to work,

My code is below:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
//get current date time with Date()
Date date = new Date();
```

Do I need to use the `Calendar` library or can I just do it with simple date format?

Comment: use [calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) would be easier and accurate

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not a date abstraction.  It's a formatting abstraction.

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you can simple use a `Calendar` which has the capacity to automatically roll the various fields of a date based on the changes to a single field, for example...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 120);
date = cal.getTime();
```

Take a closer look at [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for more details.

Yes, there is a way to do this using Joda Time, but I could type this example quicker ;)

**Update with JodaTime example**

The following is an example using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).  You could parse the `String` value directly using JodaTime, but since you've already done that, I've not bothered...

```
Date date = ...;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
dt = dt.plusDays(120);
date = dt.toDate();
```

Comment: Since this was originally marked with the [tag:swing] tag, see also [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html)..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `Joda` DateTime if possible.  The advantage is it handles TimeZone very gracefully.  Here's how to add days:

```
DateTime added = dt.plusDays(120);
```

Reference:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays(int)