# cast date to ms to add long value of duration with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, timestamp, criteria

I have a date and duration. I need to add the duration to date. Date's format is timestamp, duration's - Long (milliseconds). How can I wright criteria to deal this issue?
Practically i have something like this:
 03-17-2014 21:24:57 + 2523566;

Comment: Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or `Calendar` (or Java 8's new time API), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842934/how-to-add-days-to-java-simple-date-format/21842959#21842959)

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat to parse and convert your String to a Date, then create new Date from dt.getTime + ts

Comment: My dates and durations lays in SQL data base. I need to wright the query which wolud count it and extract to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in Java and have a java.sql.Date and a long:

```
public java.sql.Date dateAdd(java.sql.Date inputDate, long duration)
{
    return new java.sql.Date(inputDate.getTime() + duration);
}
```

A java.sql.Timestamp can be used in place of a java.sql.Date in either the argument or the return value, if required.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not criteria query. To deal this problem in java i can with the help of simple day format and other tools. But i need criteria query. I have such task