# increment now date by several days issue in java

Tags: java

I need to increment date by some days.

```
private Date now = new Date();
private Date result;

public void incrementDate(Integer days) {

    result = 

}
```

So if days equals 3 i need to increment my `now date` on 3 days and set it to `result`.

I know that java 8 has `plusDays` method in `LocalDate` class. Is there a way how to implement this in java 7.

Comment: `Calendar` and `JodaTime`

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842934/how-to-add-days-to-java-simple-date-format/21842959#21842959)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance ();
cal.setTime (now);

cal.add (Calendar.DATE, days);
```

plus other fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to do this:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE,3);
result = cal.getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the function static and pass in `now`. return `Date` and use a `Calendar`. Something like,

```
public static Date incrementDate(Date now, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

And then to test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(df.format(now));
    System.out.println(df.format(incrementDate(now, 3)));
}
```

Output here (today) is

```
2014-11-12
2014-11-15
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
String today=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(today);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 20);
String After=sdf.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(After);
Date now = new Date();
```