# Incrementing SimpleDate by days using For Loop

Tags: java, simpledateformat, jgrasp

I'm having issues using a for loop to increment a SimpleDate with the current date to a date in the future using just days.

I first get my DAYS in a `double eventDay` variable, which is returned from `public double getEventDays()`. I'm trying to GRAB this variable, and use it in another public data access-er called `public SimpleDate getEventDate()`

First off I have no idea how to grab a variable from another data access-er, or if it's even possible. But even after that I need to initialize a for loop that will essentially be something like;

```
for (int 1 = 0, i < (int)eventDay, i+=1)
{
     eventDay.nextDay(); // need to use the .nextDay() to add a day N amount of times
     return eventDay;
}
return null;
```

I know this is completely wrong, but it's what I'm basically looking for, I just have no idea how to start it off.

Comment: Either use the Java 8 Time API or Joda-Time. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842934/how-to-add-days-to-java-simple-date-format/21842959#21842959) for example

Comment: Well this isn't what I was looking for exactly, I have to use a for loop and use the nextDay method from SimpleDate API to up the day of a SimpleDate by N amount. It's for School or else I'd try using the Java 8 Time API...

Comment: Yes, put the code inside a loop and pass it the value instead of the absolute value...

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
public SimpleDateFormat getEventDate() {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    sdf.getCalendar().add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (int)getEventDays());
    return sdf;
}
```